# Invalid topology error when running script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I am trying to run a python script and I get an invalid topology rule when I get to the feature to line tool. I am using arc 10.1 but I think the script was written in 10.0. I know it was built in model builder and then converted. `Invalid Topology [Feature not found on delete.]` is the exact error.

Has anyone seen this before?

There are no topologies in the .gdb I am trying to process.

Comment: will be easier if you publish your code

Comment: There should be no difference between 10.0 or 10.1 as they both use arcpy. As user7172 suggested you should post the code to enable us to help.

Comment: Also, you seem to have traced this error back to the Feature To Line tool so if you run that outside of the model and post the exact syntax (grab using Copy Python Snippet in Results window) used alongside the exact error then we will be in a much better position to help.

Answer (score 2):

This particular tool uses the "Topology Engine" to create the output geometries from the inputs. That's why the somewhat misleading "Invalid Topology" error, it has nothing to do with topologies in the input .gdb.

Most times this error is caused by bad geometry in the input data.
Run the [Check Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Check_Geometry/001700000034000000/) tool. If anything is reported run [Repair Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Repair_Geometry/00170000003v000000/) then try to run **Feature To Line** again.

If that doesn't do it, you could read over the [Be successful overlaying large, complex datasets in Geoprocessing](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/06/15/be-successful-overlaying-large-complex-datasets-in-geoprocessing/) blog post. I have no idea what your data is like, but this steps through the workflow we typically use when evaluating these types of problems.

Comment: thanks for responding really appreciate it!The code appears to run fine in other machines. I am led to believe that it has something to do with settings or configuration. I tried running the tool on its own with the same data and the same results occur. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @Jason If you've isolated it to Feature To Line then what happens when you run just that tool on the same input data copied to and using different machines?  I see similar errors often and recently have been finding that they always resolve using gotchula's procedure.